# REGEX - How to match set of string with at least one special character anywhere?

Tags: regex

I have a problem in matching password using following regex.

```
^[A-Za-z\d[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+]{1,}]{6,}$
```

In above expression I want user to enter at least one special anywhere with remaining characters should be alphanumeric. The password length can't be less than six.

But the above expression is allowing user to enter not any special character. Could anyone please tell me how can I restrict the user to  enter at least one special character?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would anyone *not* allow more than one special character in a password?

Comment: Putting in arbitrary restrictions that force someone to use a password that is *less* strong than **they** would like is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Sorry, the exact requirement is to have at least one special character anywhere. I have edited my post.

Comment: Whilst it may be possible in a single regex, I'd recommend making the length check and the special character checks separate. Otherwise, I think you end up with a massive ((special character followed by at least 5 other characters)|(1 alpha, a special character, followed by at least 4 other characters)|(2 alpha, a special character, followed by at least 3 other characters)...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
^(?=[\w!@#$%^&*()+]{6,})(?:.*[!@#$%^&*()+]+.*)$
```

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^(?=[\w!@#0^&*()+]{6,})(?:.*[!@#0^&*()+]+.*)$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w!@#0^&*()+]{6,}       any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), '!', '@', '#', '0', '^',
                             '&', '*', '(', ')', '+' (at least 6
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [!@#0^&*()+]+            any character of: '!', '@', '#', '0',
                             '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '+' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I think an automatic explanation is not a real substitute for human explanation. Some words on what you changed would be nice. Sidenote: I'd go with the other answer; I don't really see a point in overly complicating a regex expression when it is embedded in mighty Python anyways.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of complicating your regex, how about iterating over the chars and counting the special ones

```
count = 0
for char in string:
    if isspecial(char):
        count = count+1

if count > 1:
    reject()
```

Comment: +1: This is the business solution. There's no point in complicating the regex when it is embedded in mighty Python.